# Limit of a exponential sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am stuck with this tricky limit... Any idea?
$$ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(n^2e^{-1/n}+ne^{-1/n}-n^2) $$
Of course, I am not allowed to use l'Hopital...

Comment: Why would you need l'Hospital rule in the first place ?

Answer (score 1):

You must use at least one extra term in the development (because of the $n^2$ at the beginning). So, 
$$e^{-1/n} \approx~ 1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2 n^2}-\frac{1}{6
   n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)$$

Now replace in your expression and you will arrive to $$n^2 e^{-1/n} + n e^{-1/n} - n^2 \approx-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3 n}-\frac{1}{8 n^2}+\frac{1}{30
   n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)$$

I let you concluding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the series expansion for the exponential function:

$\exp(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}$

Then we get

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(n^{2}\exp(-1/n)+n\exp(-1/n)-n^{2})=
\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(n^{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n^{2}}-\frac{1}{6n^{3}}\pm…\right)+n\left(1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n^{2}}-\frac{1}{6n^{3}}\pm…\right)-n^{2}\right)=
\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(n^{2}-n+\frac{1}{2}\pm O(\frac{1}{n^{k}})+n-1\pm O(\frac{1}{n^{k}})-n^{2}\right)=
\\
=-\frac{1}{2}
$

This is indeed the correct result as one could check with e.g. Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

for small $x$ we have $e^x = 1+x + x^2/2+.....$ therefore $e^{-1/n} \approx 1-\frac{1}{n}$ and $n^2 e^{-1/n} + n e^{-1/n} - n^2 \approx n^2(1-\frac{1}{n} + \frac {1}{2n^2}...)+ n(1-\frac{1}{n}+ \frac {1}{2n^2}...) -n^2 
= n^2 -n +\frac{1}{2}-... n -1 +\frac{1}{2n}....- n^2 =\frac{1}{2}-1=-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I think the answer is 1/2...